# Download a generated svg with a fontawesome icon

Tags: svg, d3.js, font-awesome

Download an svg with fontawesome icons

Hi everybody,
from a couple of days I've tried to implement the download of an svg, generated with d3 version 3.5.5, inside which there are fontawesome icons.
Those icons have to be filled with a custom color, specified in an ajax service from server.

The "download" action itself it's simple and works but the generated svg doesn't render the icons: it shows empty and bordered squares, as it doesn't recognize the font.

Now in the svg, as you can see [in the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ilmilanesedop/1yuzjkft/7/), icons are inside a tspan inside the ".legend-container".

I've tried these these solutions:

- link fontawesome inside svg
  `<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.5.0/css/all.min.css" type="text/css"/>`
  nope (but I may have done something wrong)
- svg local css: nope
- tspan replaced with an image that's linked to an external icon svg linked. I changed the icon color with a stunning function that calculates the filter property starting from an hex.

This last solution works but I have to replace that elements (text and tspan) with "g" tags, and this break the legend layout, making very difficoult to put every element (has to be responsive, as possible) in the structure.

Does anybody have any idea?

I'm opened to every other solutions.

Sorry for my english, I hope I'm making myself clear.

Thank you for reading!